# Change navbar login dropdown to logout ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how to change a bootstrap navbar dropdown via ajax(without page refresh) after the user logs in. Thanks

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" name= "myNavBar" id="myNavbar">
    <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact/">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="/webstore/FiberArts/">Store</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Login | Register<b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myOtherModal" href="#log-in">Login</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" href="#log-in">Register</a></li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I can get it to change but it requires page refresh

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
check this for implementation of AJAX. on success, just modify the DOM element.
You can get the DOM element(Navbar here) by Document.getElementById or various other Javascript methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the modal dialog after it appears from clicking the login/reg links, on login button click, you'd just do something like using jquery

```
$.ajax({ ..... success: { $('.dropdown').hide(); }
```

then show or append a log out link.

if you've never used jquery ajax, [jquery ajax example](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem was i wasn't referencing the drop down class directly.

Comment: i would also suggest using an ID instead of class, it's faster if you just need to reference one item. so use id="dropdown", $('#dropdown').hide()