# Change navbar login dropdown to logout without ajax

Tags: php, authentication, refresh, navbar

I am having a similar problem as in 
[Change navbar login dropdown to logout ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691687/change-navbar-login-dropdown-to-logout-ajax)

Is there any way to refresh without using ajax?

Comment: so how does your login process work ? do you post a form ?

Comment: I am using a session variable, when logging in, and the navbar.php checks  session variable to populate:

 if ($_SESSION['logedin']==1)

      {echo "<a href='logout.php' class='txt-shad'> ".$nb_logout."</a>";}  
                          
 else {echo "<a href='login.php' class='txt-shad'> ".$nb_login."</a>";}

Comment: Without ajax or without JS? Isn't this a JS question, not PHP? PHP has no client interaction. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload